# Distributed K Nearest Neighbor using RHadoop

Tags: r, machine-learning, references, rmr, rhadoop

I thought Revolution Analytics had a presentation out there about how to use RHadoop to do distributed KNN. Has anyone actually done this before, familiar with any blogs, or other references about how to do it? I'd appreciate any guidance!